# This page can’t be displayed

Tags: 2016

I created a new web application then create a new site collection.

I browse the URL but I revived

> This page can’t be displayed

It's a test environment with default settings , no configuration for IIS or DNS,

Thanks for your thoughts !

Comment: IIS bindings correct? DNS correct? Not much info to help you here.

Comment: Is your web application have host header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced this strange behavior before with SharePoint 2016. where I tried to create a new web application with the port 80 in fresh Sharepoint 2016 installation thence I create a site collection that created properly without any issue but once I tried to open it via browser I got `This page can’t be displayed`

In fact, I didn't know what was the root cause of this issue, where everything was normal without any changes.

What I have remembered I just tried to create another new web application with its site collection that worked properly without `This page can’t be displayed`.

**Note:** This will not solve the issue of your old web application, Meanwhile, you can delete the old one after creating the new one not before.then create it again with your preferred port number (in my case was 80).

Comment: Thanks Sir, let me try your suggestion and I will update you

Comment: Thanks it's worked for me , So far, I do not know what is the main reason for that error,

Answer (score 0):

Add the user from which you have created the application in local administration group on both servers e.g. SQL server and SP server and reset iis , it will solve your problem.